# Ejecutar código php por ajax al hacer click en un enlace sin recargar la página

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

intento hacer un sistema de votaciones. Tengo un código que funciona en una página de prueba. El cual al hacer click en un botón, hace una consulta a la base de datos, recoge los votos, le suma 1 y realiaz el update. Y funciona. Ejecuta el código que hay en subirvoto.php correctamente

Es este:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.subir-voto').click(function(){
        var info = $(this).data("info");
        alert(info);
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"subirvoto.php?info="+info,
        
            success:function(r){
                if(r == 1){
                    alert("Correcto");
                } else {
                    alert("No se ha podido votar");
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

y el código del botón que viene por php:

```
echo "<p><button class='subir-voto' data-info='" . $fila["id"] . "'>Me gusta (" . $fila["votos"] .")</button></p>";
```

Mis problemas es al intentar implementarlo en el código de mi página. el cual donde quiero que hagan click es en un enlace, es decir, no hay ningún formulario, y al no haber formulario, no sabría como pasar la id del producto sin tener el campo hidden dentro de un formulario, y también sin que se recargue la página al hacer click en el...

Es decir...
Cómo podría por ajax, que al hacer click en dicho enlace, pasar un dato por medio de el, y que se ejecute el código php que hay en un archivo distinto ? y todo esto sin que se recargue la página ?

EDITO: He probado con el mismísimo código en otra página a parte y funciona correctamente, pero donde tendría que funcionar no. He visto esta diferencia en la herramienta para desarrolladores

En página a parte:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Veo que aparece lo de EVENT...

En la página donde tendría que funcionar, con el mísmo código:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí no aparece lo de EVENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un botón con un [atributo data](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), posteriormente lo capturas en la función click, y haces un ajax pero en lugar de con POST con GET, algo como:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#boton').click(function(){
      var info = $(this).attr("data-info");
          $.ajax({
              type:"GET",
              url:"subirvoto.php?info="+info,
              success:function(r){
                  if(r == 1){
                      alert("Correcto");
                  } else {
                      alert("No se ha podido votar");
                 }
              }
          });
          return false;
      });
});
```

```html
<button id="boton" data-info="xxxx">Boton</button>
```

Puede ayudarte [esta entrada en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576548/how-to-pass-parameters-in-get-requests-with-jquery).

Comment: He probado con tu código, pero al presionar en el botón no hace nada, recojo el data por $_GET["info"] en donde está el archivo php destino, pero nada, edberia almenos ejecutar los alert, pero tampoco

Comment: He modificado la forma de pasar el parámetro directamente en la url

Comment: me sigue pasando igual, al darle no ejecuta los alerts de correcto o incorrecto, y tampoco ejecuta el código php de la url, he editado el hilo y te he puesto lo que tengo

Comment: Modifico la forma de capturar el data atribute.

Comment: Lo mismo, he probado despues de delcarar la variable info a hacer un alert con ella y tampoco lo realiza, parece que directamente no haga nada al presionar click en el boton. La llamada al archivo js la tengo en el head, no se si cinfluye en algo

Comment: Puede ser que no funcione por que se repite el mismo botón con la misma clase ? o deberia funcionar también

Comment: El id debe ser único, no puede haber dos elementos con el mismo id

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo por clase, no por id, ya que al volver muchas veces por cada coincidencia en la consulta en la base de datos sale varias veces. cambio el selector por el de clase pero tendría que funcionar y nada..

Comment: Lo primero es saber porque no funciona el click, puedes probar con on() y click, en lugar de click solamente. https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: He probado con: **on( "click", function() {** y tampoco. He probado a simpelmente sacar un alert("hola") al hacer click en dicho botón y nada. ¿ Puede ser a que por cada registro que muestra aparece dicho botón y al haber muchos no funciona?. En una página a parte si funciona el alert("hola") pero en la que tendría que funcionar no lo hace.

Comment: He probado con todo el código en una página a parte y funciona, coge el data-info y suma el voto en la base de datos, pero donde tendría que funcionar no lo hace

Comment: También he probado en la página a parte a ver si entraba en conflicto al haber varias botones con la misma clase, pero funciona perfectamemente

Comment: En el código que tienes el alert(info) esta antes que var info=... no imprimirá nada. Por lo demás si funciona en otra página, no se...

Comment: He editado el hilo para que veas lo que he visto en la herramienta para desarrolladores del navegador, por si así te orienta a el por qué pasa esto

Comment: Madre del amor hermoso....como va a funcionar si no tenía la llamda a JQuery :S Solucionado!